# Is there a way to force a transaction to execute sonner within a block?

Tags: solidity, mining, security

I'm building a DAPP game that would require users to submit a transaction after a specific block. The first one to have a transaction submitted and processed wins the round. As soon as the first transaction gets processed, the smart contract sets a locked flag so that others can't execute the winning function call.

My questions are when 2 or more people submit a transaction at the same block:

1 - Would paying a higher gas fee make a transaction precede another within the same block?

2 - How feasible would it be for a miner to manipulate the transaction orders so they can say which is the winner?

3 - If 5 transactions are submitted at the same block, which variables tell which will be processed first?

Comment: Miners are always scanning the mempool in the lookuot of the higher earnings, so yes, whoevere sends the higher gas on their tx is going to frontrun all the other txs

Comment: Not by definition, miners are free to choose any particular order for transactions. Usually it's highest gas price comes first.

Comment: So, if higher gas ordering is the current standard, could I, theoretically, prevent frontrunning by requiring the function to be processed only if the gas price is below a certain threshold?